# If $f$ is analytic in $D$ and $f(D)$ is a subset of a given set $G$ then $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a function $g \colon \mathbb{R} ^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and the subset $G$ of $\mathbb{C}$ given by $G=\{u+iv\in\mathbb{C} : g(u,v)=0\}$.

Moreover, assume that $\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}(u_0,v_0)\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}(u_0,v_0)\right)^2\neq0$, for all $(u_0,v_0)\in G$.

Show that if a function $f:D\to\mathbb{C}$ defined in a domain $D$ is analytic in $D$ and $f(D)=\{f(z):z\in D\}$ is a subset of $G$ then $f$ is constant.

[Hint: Use the fact that $g(u(x,y), v(x,y))=0$ for all $z=x+iy\in D$ where $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$.]

---

What I've got:

- $f$ is analytic, so $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.
- We have to prove that $f$ is constant, so $f'(z)=0$ or $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0$

And then I'm stuck... I don't understand what the second equation (the partials squared not equal to 0) represents and how it relates to the problem.
Is there anyone who could give me a (second) hint? Much appreciated!

Comment: How smooth is $g$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: We have $g(u(x,y),v(x,y))=0$. Then, if we compute the partial derivative with respect to $x$, we get
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}(u(x,y),v(x,y))+ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y)\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}(u(x,y),v(x,y))=0$$

Do the same for the variable $y$, put $u_0=u(x,y)$, $v_0=v(x,y)$, and use the Cauchy-Riemann relations.

Answer (score 0):

With open non-empty $D, $ the Open Mapping Theorem implies that if $f$ is not locally constant then $f(E)$ is open whenever $E$ is an open component of $D$ on which $f$ is not a constant. But then $\{(u,v)\in R^2 :u+iv\in f(E)\}$ is a non-empty open subset of $R^2$ on which $g=0$ but $\nabla^2 g\ne 0$, which is absurd. If $D$ is connected then $D$ is the only open component of $D$, and $f$ is constant. (Some use "domain" in complex calculus to mean a connected non-empty open set. Some of us don't like it, as "domain" has another meaning, as in  "domain of a function." )